# Why is there a `std::llabs`?

Tags: c++, c++11

Looking at the `std::abs` overloads form [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), I realized that there are two different functions that do the exact same thing, both being introduced in C++11:

```
long long abs( long long n );
```

and

```
long long llabs( long long n );
```

Is there any reason why `std::llabs` was introduced? Because of possible ambiguities? (although I think the later can be resolved via a simple cast).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for C source compatibility. C doesn't have function overloading (sans some magic macros using `_Generic` from C11).

So, if you want your code to compile in both C and C++ modes, i.e. as some kind of library, you can do the following and have the code compile successfully in both C++ and C modes.

```
// foo.c
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
long long foo(long long val) {
    return llabs(some_value);
}
```

If you were to call `abs` in the above snippet, different functions would've been called in C and C++ modes.

Comment: Small quibble: C11's `_Generic` feature isn't *directly* related to macros, though macro definitions are probably the only reasonable place to use it.

Comment: Yes, but `llabs` is new (introduced in C++11), so why should I expect to use it in C? If it was the other way around it would have made more sense.

Comment: It is not new.  It was introduced in C99.

Comment: @paddy Hmmm, in the [cppreference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) it says *since C++11*. I guess you referred to C, which probably had it. I just wonder why the need to "import" it into C++11.

Comment: @vsoftco it's in C++ since C++11. It's in C since C99.

Comment: Follow the link to the [C documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs).  That's the C++ documentation, which describes `std::llabs`, not `llabs`.

Comment: @paddy Exactly. My question is why is there a `std::llabs` in C++11 when you also have a `std::abs`, which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I believe my answer answers this question: it's source compatibility. You can't have call to `abs` in C, at least not if you want the same function called as you'd have in C++

Comment: The C++ standard includes most of the C standard library by reference. C++08 references the C90 standard, which did not have `llabs()`. C++11 references the C99 standard, which does have `llabs()`. There was no particular reason to exclude `llabs()` from C++11.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, makes sense now.

Comment: @vsoftco Amusingly, C++11 also includes C99 header `stdbool.h`, as `cstdbool`.  In C99, this header contains the macros `#define bool _Bool`, `#define true 1`, and `#define false 0`, along with `#define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1`; in C++11, as those are already C++ keywords, it just contains `#define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1`, making it explicitly useless for C++ programs.  However, using it guarantees that any file intended to be compiled as both C and C++ can use the same syntax for both languages' boolean types, increasing C compatibility.

Comment: The fact that the C++ standard includes a header that explicitly does nothing whatsoever for C++ programs, for the specific intent of increasing C compatibility, says everything that needs to be said.